# Customized color function for 3D

Tags: plotting, color

I have the following 3D function.

```
minMax = {0, 1}; 
col = {RGBColor[0, 0, 0.65], RGBColor[0, 0, 1], RGBColor[0, 0.5, 1],RGBColor[0, 0.75, 1], RGBColor[0, 1, 1], RGBColor[0.5, 1, 0.5],RGBColor[1, 1, 0], RGBColor[1, 0.75, 0], RGBColor[1, 0.5, 0], RGBColor[1, 0, 0], RGBColor[0.65, 0, 0]};
colAll = Blend[col, Rescale[#, minMax]] &;

    With[{is = 4, p = 9},  Plot3D[(i1^p/(is^p + i1^p)) (i2^p/(is^p + i2^p)), {i1, 0, 8}, {i2, 0,8}, ColorFunction -> colAll, Mesh -> 8,   PlotTheme -> "Scientific"]]
```

[image]

But when I used built in function  `ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"` I am getting desired result.

[image]

Why my custom color only works one way? How can I fix this? Thanks..

Comment: use `ColorFunction -> (colAll[#3] &)`?

Comment: ... or change `#` to `#3` in the definition of  `colAll`.

Comment: That works. Thank you..

Comment: I will use `ColorFunction -> (colAll[#3] &)` since I have 2D figures so I can use `ColorFunction -> (colAll[#2] &)`  Thanks again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing either the setting for `ColorFunction` to

```
ColorFunction -> (colAll[#3] &)
```

or the definition of `colAll` to

```
colAll = Blend[col, Rescale[#3, minMax]] &;
```

gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]